# c++ how to create my own warning in compilation time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation, compiler-errors, static-assert

I want to create my own warning in compilation time and not in pre-processor (as I've seen a few answers to)
Let's say we have:

```
class A
{
private:
    explicit A(A const& other);
};
```

now if the user does:

`A first;`

and then:

`A second(first);`

he'll get an error that copy constructed is not implemented or whatever.. bare in mind that my code has a lot of inheritances in it... as well as referring me to the H file A is implemented in and not where I tried to use copy constructor...

so.. instead of the compiler's default warning I'd like to create my own....
something like.. "You cannot use copy constructor"

Help?
Thanks!

Comment: Switch to gcc and use __attribute__((warning("my message"))) ;-)

Comment: It isn't clear if you want warning messages or error messages, please clarify.

Comment: It's odd that your compiler is not referring you to the line where the user does `A second(first)`, since that's an attempt to call a private function.

Comment: why do you want a warning and not an error?

Comment: The way to tell the user not to declare a copy constructor, on a compiler where `static_assert` is available, is to declare the constructor `= delete`. But this question is highly ambiguous; please clarify whether you want a warning or what.

Comment: sorry, but what is = delete ? :)

Comment: @Alon Clearly answer our question first. Do you want a *warning* yet still compile everything else, or an *error*?

Answer (score 3):

Using a `static_assert` with a user-define message will trigger this error message during compilation

```
class A
{
private:
    A() {}

    explicit A(A const& /* other */) 
    { 
        static_assert(false, "You cannot use copy constructor"); 
    }
};

int main()
{
    A first;    
    A second(first); // compile error
}
```

Output on [LiveWorkSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3S7pV3%243)

Note this will produce an error and not a warning. However, it is almost always best to use a "warnings as errors" compiler option and to explicity (i.e. documented with a comment) disable warnings that you know are innocuous.

Comment: It's quite useless though, you would rather do: `A(A const&) = delete` because it's **idiomatic** in C++11.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Of course you are right, but I interpreted the question as how to customize compiler messages in general.

Comment: what is A(A const&) = delete?

Comment: @user2017469 that is a new C++11 feature in which otherwise automatically generated functions can be removed from a class

Comment: I am using VS 2012 and it still gives me syntax error, how to make it compile ?

Comment: @user2017469 if you want to make the code compile, make the copy constructor public.

Comment: @Alon, gcc >= 4.7, clang >= 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Without preprocessor, using only standard C++, it's unreal. You can use `static_assert`, but it's not warning.

Comment: static assert will only make it _never_ compile.. I wanted something to do in compilation time, not the preprocessor,